# Can't edit files in www-data with correct permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

Because our site is actually in development, I wanted to give the users within the webadmins group the permission to edit files in /var/www/. I've already tried these commands :

```
chgrp -R webadmins /var/www
chmod -R 770 /var/www
```

The problem is that only my user can edit the files in that directory. It is in the webadmins group, like the other users. The parent directory also has the executable bit set. I've even tried to `chmod -R 777 /var/www`, but it didn't work either.

Any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: You might be missing `usermod -a -G www-data (username)`.

Comment: I already did it for the other users.

Comment: Have you tried `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` already?

Comment: I've check the owners of the folder and it's owned by www-data:webadmins. Before trying with the webadmins group, I added the web admins to the www-data group, and the folder was already owned by www-data:www-data, but I had the same issue